# Android - Linkify Problem

Tags: android, linkify

I seem to be having trouble with the linkify I am using in my Custom Adapter.  For some reason I recieve the following stack track when I click on one of the links:

```
06-07 20:49:34.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.startActivity(ApplicationContext.java:550)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:248)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:216)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6560)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-07 20:49:34.745: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(813):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
```

**Here is the code that is calling it**:

```
    TextView bot = new TextView( c );
    bot.setText(li.getBottomText());
    bot.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    bot.setTextSize(12);
    bot.setPadding(50, 35, 0, 10);
    Linkify.addLinks(bot, Linkify.ALL);
    rL.addView(bot,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I understand what the error is saying but I am not sure how to fix it.  Does anyone have any ideas?  **Thanks in advance for your help**!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this is a lot simpler than I had originally thought.  The problem was that when I was passing the context to my custom adapter I was passing the **getApplicationContext()** which is not the same as using the **this** identifier.

**INCORRECT WAY**:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( 
                mContext,
                itemList);
```

**CORRECT WAY**:

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( 
                this,
                itemList);
```