# Clickable Links inside listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, textview

List view clickable link poblem.

I'm using the following code inside the getView() to generate a clickable link in a listview.

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String linkText = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
```

This code works fine on a textview which is not in a listview but when i use it for a textview within a list view the following exception is raised on clicking the link.

```
AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity
context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: Something sounds weird to me.. this code is inside a custom adapter right? is there an onClickListener in it?

Comment: yeah this is inside the custom adapters getView method. No there isn't and onClickListner to it.

Comment: umm.. I found this http://www.stevenmarkford.com/solution-to-android-error-calling-startactivity-outside-activity-context-requires-flag_activity_new_task/ dont know if it will help

Comment: thanks but i found a simpler fix. will post in sometime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993112/android-linkify-problem/). I just had to change the constructor call from

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( mContext, itemList);
```

to

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter( this, itemList);
```

Comment: Great Answer, for those who struggle to solve. Simply, from where you are initialising your `Adapter` be it any adapter `CustomAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` or your regular `BaseAdapter`, just put `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` or something else

Comment: Thank you soooo much, was going crazy trying to figure out why i was getting this error :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView2 );
   SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( http://google.com" );
   textView2.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
   Linkify.addLinks( textView2, Linkify.WEB_URLS );

     Try this one....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the ApplicationContext was used for inflating the views.
Changed it to ActivityContext, now it works!