# Error While clickng on TextView Hyperlinks

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, clickable

I want to show an Html formatted text in a list View. I used a TextView in the adapter.
this is my code in the adapter :

```
txtBody.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString));
txtBody.setLinksClickable(true);
txtBody.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

the problem is : when I touch a hyperlink on the TextView it crashes with this error in LogCat:

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918517/calling-startactivity-from-outside-of-an-activity-context)

Comment: before asking question please do some searching on google.

Comment: I do not call the external Activity my self,so I have no intent to set setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277474/clickable-links-inside-listview) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976171/setting-autolink-property)

It because of context you are setting to your adapter.