# Spannable String Error

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to display some text in an alert dialog box as a hyperlink. Part of the process requires me to use SpannableString to format some text. The problem is that my application experiences a runtime error on the SpannableString part of my code.

```
TextView Tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("www.google.com");
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
Tv.setText(s);
Tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I looked in the DDMS and the Error says Java.Lang.NullPointerException. Has anyone experienced this? I Should be able to pass the SpannableString method a hardcoded string. I do not know why it is crashing like this.

This is the OnCreate function in my java file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    TextView Tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewH);

    Tv.setText("GO!");
    //System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++");        
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("www.google.com");
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    Tv.setText(s);
    Tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("About T2M");
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_about_t2m, null));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
    {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}); 
    //System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    dialog.create();  
    dialog.show();


}
```

This is the text view in my XML file:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textviewH"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Humium"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

[image: My Layout]

Comment: Could you give us the line where the NullPointerException occurs plz ?

Comment: I did some tests using println and found that the error happens right at the SpannableString construction line

Comment: Are you sure that it could not come from the **findViewById** ?
Because I can't think of any reason why the **SpannableString** would go for a NullPointerException...

Comment: You are correct. It seems that my textview is not properly linked. This is a custom alertdialog. How do I link the textview box?

Comment: I even went into the graphic view of the activity and changed the id of the text box and told it to change all references to that text box. When I returned to the java file, the id that I entered before was updated with the new id. I link all my text boxes in the exact same way. I do not know why this one is acting like this

Comment: Could you plz give the code of the Layout and the java code linking your AlertDialog to the custom Layout ? It will more easy to understand what you're missing :)

Comment: The first set text line that I added helped me confirm that my textview box is not linked. You can see from the XML file and java file that the IDs match though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think the issue come from the inflation process.
It seems like you're trying to access the TextView before you inflate the Layout. So **findViewById** won't find anything as it will search in the Activity Layout.

The trick here would be inflate your **custom Layout** first (, here's an exemple of what you could do :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //Inflating the custom Layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_about_t2m, null);

    //Searching for the TextView in it
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewH);

    //Then making the links
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("www.google.fr");
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

    //Adding the text to the View and make the links clickable 
    tv.setText(s);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    //Finally applying the custom view we inflated (R.layout.activity_about_t2m) on the AlertDialog and ....
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setTitle("About T2M");
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            } 
    );
```

**Edit 1:**
I made a mistake with this example… In your case the **getApplicationContext()** should be **this** (I made the fix in the code)

More info here : 
[Android - Linkify Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993112/android-linkify-problem)

**Edit 2:** 
Ok, so now that should be understandable right ?

Comment: What do you do with view after you create it? I do not see it used anywhere

Comment: I find the TextView inside : 

TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);

Comment: Ok im going to try this out

Comment: So I used your updated code

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.id.textviewH, null);

But I am still getting the same error. This time it crashes on that line of code though

Comment: Hmm, can you show the logcat error ? It probably comes from the 'this' statement, I assumed you were working in the **onCreate** of an Activity so the 'this' statement should refers to that Activity.

Comment: Just copy/past the code I gave you, it should do the trick ;)
Btw, do you use something like setContentView(…) in your onCreate method at some point ?

Comment: When you link your text box, what id are you using? Shouldn't it be the same id that you used  when you created view?

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, no wonder that you can make it :D
Give me five, I'll edit my answer so that you understand...

Comment: Excellent! One last question though. How do I hide the web address so that only a single clickable word is displayed?

Comment: I probably would use the <a> tag from HTML : 
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("<a href="wwww.google.fr">Google</a>");

Comment: There is a problem though, the application crashes when I click the link.

Comment: What does loggat say ?

Comment: Finally got the link to work! Thanks for your help man
[Salute](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2vct5hy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**This Code is working fine for me. I hope this will help you as well.**

```
TextView richTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_aboutus);
    // this is the text we'll be operating on
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hi Click on Google.com and yahoo.com or Pmstudy.com");
    text.setSpan(
            new URLSpan("http://www.google.com/"),
            13, 22, 0);
    text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.yahoo.com/"),
            28, 36, 0);
    text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.pmstudy.com"), 41, 51, 0);

    richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    richTextView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Enjoy......

Thanks ,
Mukesh

Comment: I am using a custom alert dialog. How do I do this with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
**You can Use Same code in your custom Dialog as well. This is currently working for me.

you need to inflate your custom-dialog-layout in your code .**

custom_dialog.xml

//this xml is for custom Dialog.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_aboutus"
        android:text="Hi Click on Google.com and yahoo.com or Pmstudy.com"/>

</LinearLayout>



package PackageName;

// import Files

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button show_dialog=(Button) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    show_dialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog d=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            TextView richTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_aboutus);
            SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hi Click on Google.com and yahoo.com or Pmstudy.com");
            text.setSpan(
                    new URLSpan("http://www.google.com/"),
                    13, 22, 0);
            text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.yahoo.com/"),
                    28, 36, 0);
            text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.pmstudy.com"), 41, 51, 0);

            richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            richTextView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            d.setContentView(v);
            d.show();

        }
    });

    }

}
```