# setText not working in SpannableString

Tags: java, android

I am trying to setup a tooltip using a OnCreateOptionsMenu, however I am getting an error when trying to setText(text).

**CODE:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.puzzle_tips, menu);

    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("TOP TIP:\nShake screen to reshuffle puzzle");
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.tips_icon);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    text.setSpan(span, 31, 32, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuPuzzleTips);
    Tooltip.Builder builder = new Tooltip.Builder(menuItem)
        .setCornerRadius(10f)
        .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        .setText(text);
    builder.show();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
error: no suitable method found for setText(SpannableString)
method Builder.setText(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; SpannableString cannot be converted to int)
method Builder.setText(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; SpannableString cannot be converted to String)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spannable String Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033479/spannable-string-error)

Comment: i think spannable string apply into text view not menu item. if you want apply some style in menu item then it apply into menu item.xml file.

Comment: what's this Tooltip Builder API? Obviously it does not accept Spannables.

Comment: Is there anyway i could write this without the Spannables?